# Unordered selection documents from mongodb by ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a problem. I need to get a documents from my mongodb using mongoid in Rails. I have an array of ids like ["54397dea477269151d000000", "543ad4bc477269c09f000000", "543ad4bc474269c09f000000"]. And if I find docs like:

```
Item.find(ids)
```

It returns an ordered array of objects. But i need the objects be equivalent to ids array. is there any chance to get it by one selection request to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to do it outside MongoDB:

```
ids   = [ ... ]
items = Item.find(ids).sort_by { |i| ids.index(i.id) }
```

If your `ids` are strings rather than object IDs, you'll have to handle the type conversion yourself:

```
ids   = %w[54397dea477269151d000000 543ad4bc477269c09f000000 543ad4bc474269c09f000000]
items = Item.find(ids).sort_by { |i| ids.index(i.id.to_s) }
```

If you're doing this sort of thing a lot then add your own class method:

```
def self.find_in_order(ids)
  ids = ids.map(&:to_s) # Or force them to be object IDs instances and leave out the to_s below...
  find(ids).sort_by { |i| ids.index(i.id.to_s) }
end
```

This sort of "do it by hand in Ruby" thing is quite common when working with MongoDB.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, MongoDB's query "language" is very limited.